# Raw image data without any format (non-standard, just the data array) to be loaded and drew with GWT

Tags: gwt, image-processing, image-rendering

Did anyone have experience on doing image rendering or processing with GWT?

I am stuck on the GWT client-side image rendering. Since the image that I need to display is the non-standard format (imagine as a data array), I cannot create an Image object on client-side to render it. What I did was to set the RGBA value of each pixel using the HTML5 element with GWT (ImageData Class), which is extremely slow. I wonder if there is a way to improve the rendering speed or even has a better method to rendering the raw image data? Cuz, after drawing image on client-side, my next step is to do some pixel level manipulation which is also needed to work in real time.

Comment: What about writing a servlet that will do all image processing?

Comment: Yes. I have written a servlet to sent the data array to client-side, and the servlet can do the image processing. But the point is how to draw this data array on a canvas. The image has not format like jpeg or gif, cannot use the setContentType(), just the array.

Comment: So convert image to this format.

Comment: But the image that I want to draw is medical image that should be lossless, so it is not good to convert the image format.